# Hibernate x Multithreading = org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance was altered from 97 to 96

Tags: spring, multithreading, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

So I have this `@Controller`'s method, which calls my `@Service` (it implements `Runnable` and has a `@Repository` autowired) method to persist a new `@Entity Transcription`.

`@Controller`'s method

```
public void serviceMethod() {
    Transcription transcription = new Transcription();
    transcription.setBotOutput(chatBot.getText());
    transcription.setCustomerInput(request);
    transcription.setDtime(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    transcription.setSessionId(chatBot.getSessionId());
    transcription.setStatus(chatBot.getStatus());
    transcription.setTopic(chatSession.predicates.get("topic"));            
    transcription.setIsUnderstand(isUnderstand);
    transcription.setSessionsId(chatSession.getId());
            
    transcriptionService.setTranscription(transcription);
    Thread t = new Thread(transcriptionService);
    t.start();
    t.join();
}
```

`@Service`

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    @Async
    public void run() 
    {
        try {
            transcriptionRepository.save(transcription);//session.persist(transcription);        
            
        } catch (HibernateException ex) 
        {
            logger.error("HibernateException : " + ex, ex);   
        }                     
    }
```

`@Repository`

```
@Repository
@Scope("prototype")
public interface TranscriptionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transcription, Long> {
    List<Transcription> findAllBySessionId(String sessionId);
}
```

The problem I'm facing is when I load-test it (`jMeter`) - sometimes an exception appear:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of pl.sprint.chatbot.db.Transcription was altered from 97 to 96

Can anyone point me to the right direction where the issue lies?

Comment: You should really read again the spring docs about async and singleton beans. Your code only works with one request at the time!

Comment: @MartinFrey Should I provide `scope="prototype"` to my Service also? And how come the jMeter tests pass? I've tested it with 900 threads simultaniously.

Comment: You are setting a member in a singleton and then call run for an arbitrary thread. At least you will simply miss some entities to be persisted. (I assume that your jmeter test does not validate the database count.)
You dont need all the threading overhead anyway for that simple usecase. Just send the entity to the service as a parameter to the transactional „run“ method instead of setting the member.

Comment: @MartinFrey So what you're saying essentially is to forget about creating a `new Thread` alltogether, right? Please correct me if I misunderstood... it's a legacy code I have to manage.

Comment: If you dont do anything special with that member except call run(), yes.

Comment: @MartinFrey Thanks a bunch :) What I'm into here is turning a 'just-learned-Java' code into a proper Spring app.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding a simple transactional check inside my `@Service`'s `run()`, like this:

```
if (transcription.getId()!=null && transcriptionRepository.existsById(transcription.getId()))
    transcriptionRepository.save(transcription);//session.persist(transcription);
```